# RS Form delete with message

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, rsform

I am using RS Forms Pro and I am able to view a list of submitted forms via a menu link. I am able to *view*, *edit* and *download* the forms from this page. I have since added *delete* functionality which works as expected. I followed the excellent guide [here](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/rsform-pro/frequently-asked-questions/how-to-create-a-delete-submission-button-in-manage-directories.html)

What I am trying to do now is probably quite simple however I cannot figure it out.

When the 'delete' button is pressed, the form is deleted and the page refreshes, great. However I would like to display a message (presumably within the system-message div) that reads (something like)

> successfully deleted

The delete functionality works however I will include my code for reference.

The script called on form display is as follows (this is set in RS Form config);

```
// First we have to check the "action" parameter from the URL
$action = JRequest::getWord('action');
if ($action == "delete") {

// If it returns true it will continue running the script 
  $id_value = JRequest::getInt('id');
  $formId_value = JRequest::getInt('formId');

// For security reasons we verify if the user has the right to edit submissions using RSFormProHelper
  if ($id_value && $formId_value && RSFormProHelper::canEdit($formId_value,$id_value)){

// If user has enough permission rights, run the query
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $db->setQuery("DELETE FROM #__rsform_submission_values WHERE `SubmissionId`='". $id_value."'");
    $db->execute();
    $db->setQuery("DELETE FROM #__rsform_submissions WHERE `SubmissionId`='". $id_value."'");
    $db->execute();

// Redirect the user back to Manage directories 
    $itemId_value = JRequest::getInt('Itemid');
    $mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_rsform&view=directory&Itemid='.$itemId_value, false));
  }

// If the user does not have permission to edit, he will be prompted with the language override created earlier:
  else
    $formLayout = JText::_('RSFP_DELETE_ERROR');
}
```

The code for my delete buton is as follows (override of com_rsform);

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_rsform&formId='.$this->params->get('formId').'&action=delete&id='.$item->SubmissionId);?>">delete</a>
```

When I view the page source I can see the empty div above my form where the system message would presumably go?

```
<div id="system-message-container"></div>
```

I understand this is related to RS Forms however I am wanting to understand how I pass a value to the system-message `div` upon successful deletion.

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `enqueueMessage` function to display a message in the system output section.

In the code you've provided, you will see the following:

```
$mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_rsform&view=directory&Itemid='.$itemId_value, false));
```

Replace it with the following:

```
$mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_rsform&view=directory&Itemid='.$itemId_value, false), 'successfully deleted', 'success');
```

***For ease of view:***

```
$url  = 'index.php?option=com_rsform&view=directory&Itemid='.$itemId_value;
$msg  = 'successfully deleted';
$type = 'success';
$mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_($url, false), $msg, $type);
```

**Update:**

Sorry, it turns out that passing a message in the redirect function is deprecated. Instead, `enqueueMessage` should be used before the redirect, like so:

```
$url  = 'index.php?option=com_rsform&view=directory&Itemid='.$itemId_value;
$msg  = 'successfully deleted';
$type = 'success';
$mainframe->enqueueMessage($msg, $type);
$mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_($url, false));
```

Comment: @johnny_s - You're welcome as always ;)

Comment: @johnny_s - See my update

Comment: your first answer works though? Is is simply depreciated - but will still work?

Comment: @johnny_s - Yup, my first code snippet will still work, it's just simply deprecated and will probably be removed in Joomla 4.0 which is ages away